# Interacting with a Flex App from Flash CS3

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a panorama viewer in Flash in which I want to embed a small Flex application. I've managed to load the Flex swf into the Flash like this:

```
private var loader:Loader = new Loader();

var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("SimpleImageViewer.swf");
loader.load(req);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imgViewerLoaded);

imgViewerLoaded(event:Event)
{
    imageViewer = loader.content;
    addChild(imageViewer);
    imageViewer.showImage("test.jpg", "Test Image");
}
```

Now, the thing is that I need to be able to call a method on the imageViewer, which I've defined in my Flex App like this:

```
public function showImage(source:String, heading:String = ""):void
{
    //Show the image
}
```

It is also being added to the ExternalInterface using

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("showImage", showImage);
```

How can I call that method from my AS3 Flash? Just calling it as `imageViewer.showImage(...)` gives this error:

> ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property showImage not found on _SimpleImageViewer_mx_managers_SystemManager and there is no default value.
>
> at UserInterface/imgViewerLoaded()

This is the entire SimpleImageViewer.mxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="100" minHeight="100" backgroundColor="#2B2B2B" creationComplete="onCreationComplete(event)" backgroundGradientAlphas="[1.0, 1.0]" backgroundGradientColors="[#2B2B2B, #2B2B2B]" verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
<mx:Image x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" scaleContent="true" maintainAspectRatio="true" id="picture"/>
<mx:Image width="100%" height="42" x="0" y="0" id="headingBg" source="@Embed(source='/bilder/topList.png')" scaleContent="true" maintainAspectRatio="false"/>
<mx:Label x="4" y="0" width="100%" height="43" id="headingTxt" fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="32" color="#FFFFFF" textAlign="center"/>

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.events.ResizeEvent;
        
        public function showImage(source:String, heading:String = ""):void
        {
            picture.source = source;
            picture.load();
            headingTxt.text = heading;
        }
        
        protected function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
        {               
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("showImage", showImage);
            Security.allowDomain("localhost");
        }


    ]]>
</mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

And the ImageViewer interface:

```
package tikab.lizzan
{
    public interface ImageViewer
    {
        function showImage(source:String, heading:String = ""):void ;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error indicates a problem with typing. Are you implementing an interface? You need to cast imageViewer as its interface type, so flash knows there is a method called "showImage". ... One other thing - the error is at imgViewerLoaded() - but you don't appear to be calling it there. Altered code?

Comment: @Bosworth99: Added the missing call. I've tried using an interface, as per @weltraumpirat's answer, but that just gives me another error message (see my comment there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited:

From the flex documentation:

> If an application is loaded into
>   another application, a SystemManager
>   will still be created, but will not
>   manage an application window,
>   depending on security and domain
>   rules. Instead, it will be the content
>   of the Loader that loaded it and
>   simply serve as the parent of the
>   sub-application

In other words: When you load your flex application into another application, the content property of the loader object will not point directly to the application itself, but to a [SystemManager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/SystemManager.html)instance, which acts as the parent of the actual Application object.  Your method calls must therefore be directed at `loader.content.getChildAt(0)`.

To do this in a type-safe way:

1. create an Interface
2. have your flex document class implement it
3. cast the first Child of your Loader object's content to that same interface

Or (not type-safe, but quick) simply call the method using bracket syntax:

```
loader.content.getChildAt(0)["showImage"]();
```

or cast `loader.content.getChildAt(0)` to a dynamic type, like Object or MovieClip, as @_asMan recommended.

Edit:

You are also missing some important declaration statements in your code.  This is what the imageViewerLoaded function should look like:

```
function imgViewerLoaded(event:Event)
{
    var imgViewer:MovieClip = loader.content.getChildAt(0) as MovieClip;
    addChild(loader.content);
    imgViewer.showImage("test.jpg", "Test Image");
}
```

`function` and `var` should *never* be considered optional - they help you to prevent messing up your class hierarchy and type references. (You can omit `var` if you have `imgViewer` declared as a member variable somewhere else, of course)  I also changed the name from "imageViewer" to ensure there is no ambiguous reference - the error statement you posted below implies a risk ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still no go. The quick way gives me the same error as earlier, casting to an Interface gives me: `TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert _SimpleImageViewer_mx_managers_SystemManager@1ec040e1 to tikab.lizzan.ImageViewer.
 at UserInterface/imageViewerLoaded()`

Comment: You seem to have a problem with your class hierarchy.  Make sure your class imports and declarations are correct.

Comment: Still getting the same error, unfortunately. Oh, my comment was in regard to your earlier comment, got a bit weird there...=)

Comment: I edited my answer instead, because I felt the comment to be a bit unreadable ;)

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, I had the imageViewer as a member variable elsewhere. Still, copying and pasting your code gives me the same error again. This might be a clue, but no solutions: http://troygilbert.com/2009/05/loading-flex-based-swfs-in-as3-only-swfs/ Any ideas?

Comment: Like I said: Your class hierarchy is probably broken.  Your SimpleImageViewer class (the loaded swf's document class) seems to extend mx.managers.SystemManager, which should be fine when casting to MovieClip. But the showImage method is not properly declared.  Where is that declaration snippet you posted in your question located?

Comment: I've added the entire SimpleImageViewer source to my question.

Comment: I have edited my answer.  You should also make sure the application actually implements the interface - there is no `implements="tikab.lizzan.ImageViewer"` attribute in the mxml you posted.

Comment: Thanks, I could have sworn that I put it there but it must have somehow disappeared. Put it back, tried getting the child of the SystemManager (apparently you have to use `rawChildren.getChildAt(0)`), but what I get from there now is a Preloader, not my ImageViewer. Figured I had to wait until loading was done, and now, finally, I manage to get my ImageViewer from the SystemManager - as the second child. 1000 thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT #2:

Try this:

```
function imgViewerLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    var manager:SystemManager = event.target.content as SystemManager;
    var content:ImageViewer = manager.application as ImageViewer;
    addChild(viewer);
    viewer.showImage();
}
```

This builds on weltraumpirat's helpful insight that the content type is actually a SystemManager object.  Based on everything I see, I think this will work and be a little cleaner.  Good luck!

** of course, note that you would have to modify your posted MXML to implement your interface, as I suspect you've already done

EDIT #1:

---

Based on your messages above, I found some of my code that does the same kind of thing:

```
private function loadCompleted(event:Event):void {
        currentClip = event.target.content as MovieClip;
        loader.unload();
        displayClip();
}
```

So you might want to also try looking at the contents of:

```
event.target.content
```

Try the following code to see what the type is, then use that information for casting:

```
var contents:* = event.target.content;
var className:String = flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName( contents );
trace("Class name was: " + className);
```

From there you might be able to access the method a little more cleanly with code along the lines of the following:

```
function imgViewerLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    var viewer:TypeThatYouFound = loader.content as TypeThatYouFound;
    addChild(viewer);
    viewer.showImage();
}
```

Of course, it might just turn out that the event contents are the exact same as the Loader contents.  In which case, this approach wouldn't be significantly better.  But, it's worth a shot.

Hope that helps in some way,

~gMale

---

Ok.  So I won't even ask why you're doing this in reverse (typically, you go from flash to flex not the other way around. It's common to import swfs into Flex not Flex into SWFs).

The first thing that comes to mind is that you probably are not creating a class for your Flex code.  To expose your functions, you're going to have to let somebody know that your object is different than a typical SimpleImageViewer.

Depending on how you designed things, you might need to make a custom class like

```
public class MySimpleImageViewer extends SimpleImageViewer {
        public function showImage(source:String, heading:String = ""):void {
            //Show the image
        }
}
```

Then have your MXML file instantiate this with the following syntax:

```
<local:MySimpleImageViewer />
```

With your approach being a little unorthodox, it's hard to say, exactly what you need.  If this doesn't help, try posting your Flex code and we can go from there...

Hope that helps,

~gMale

Comment: Your statement regarding Flash and Flex is flawed: 1) You don't "import" when you load an SWF at runtime (which is what was asked). Importing is done at compile time.  2) Both Flex and Flash applications are compiled into SWF files.  I see no reason why you should not load a "Flex" SWF from a "Flash" SWF, or why the other way around should be simpler - the compiled byte code is exactly the same.

Comment: @weltraumpirat: thanks for your response. However, you are debating semantics. In English to "import" means to bring something in. That is what I meant. Based on the context of my statements, it's pretty clear that my main idea related to bringing files of one application into another in a way that was *less common*. It's also equally evident that Flex applications are compiled down to SWF files. Further I never said bringing Flex to Flash SHOULDN'T be done. I offered my opinion that it is uncommon, in an attempt to illuminate why this approach might be trickier than expected.

Comment: @gmale: You were using a term that has strong semantic meaning in programming contexts, so yes, I was debating semantics - if you said you "had a virus" I wouldn't assume you were talking about the flu, either.  I also don't see why loading a Flash SWF into a Flex SWF should be less common, or even trickier than the other way around, and you fail to provide a convincing explanation or a source for this statement.

Comment: @gmale: As for why, the Flash is an existing application which I have no desire to re-write in Flex, and the imageViewer was so much easier to implement in Flex - probably because me and Flash aren't the best of friends...=)

Comment: @weltraumpirat: after reading your comments on other posts as well, you seem to be the type of contributor who likes to debate things that don't matter. Although I wholeheartedly disagree with everything you've said above (context gives words their meaning and my main point was abundantly clear), I won't waste further energy debating your response because it doesn't help the OP get the help/solution they're seeking.

Comment: @Lizzan: I see that you've updated your question with the MXML code and that you and weltraumpirat were able to find something that works.  When I get time later today, I'll take a look at what you've got and see if I can add any perspective (because, after reading your comments that you're "getting the ImageViewer from the SystemManager - as the second child," it sounds like things might be a little clunky) :). I'm glad you got stuff working, though!

Comment: @gmale (That comes out as gmail every time! =)) Thanks, some perspective would be much appreciated - I have a lot left to learn about both Flash and Flex. Yes, it's a bit clunky, but I'm happy it works - was close to giving up there for a while...

Comment: @Lizzan: I've updated my message with what I would try if I were in your shoes.  Basically, checking the event contents.  Chances are, it will be the exact same as the Loader because I suspect event.target *is* the loader object, but I would check just in case.

Comment: @gmale: Suit yourself. It's always a easier to troll than provide thorough answers.

Comment: @weltraumpirat: I just removed my gut response comment to what you just wrote... cause it wasn't nice. lol. Overall, I think we're all trying to help.  That's what matters. I don't find it helpful in the least to debate unrelated semantics but that's just my opinion. Others might disagree. No hard feelings, of course. It's just none of us are getting paid for this and time is valuable. So it can be frustrating to go back and forth over unnecessary quibbles.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will work but, have you tried to case it as an object?

```
imgViewerLoaded(event:Event)
{
    imageViewer = loader.content;
    addChild(imageViewer);
    Object( loader.content ).showImage();
}
```

or perhaps casing as the base class if you have one assigned. I used Application as an example

```
var loadedApp:Application = Application( loader.content );
loadedApp.showImage();
```

Comment: It should be "casting", not "casing". ;)  This has one quirk, though: Both the loading and the loaded file will have to include the same class file, which can result in file size being significantly bloated.  It is more advisable to use interfaces for these purposes.

Comment: Thanks, but casting it as an object gives me the same error as before: `ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property showImage not found on _SimpleImageViewer_mx_managers_SystemManager and there is no default value.`